# Dúvidas git & github

Tags: git, github

Comecei a usar o git recentemente para versionamento e, como qualquer novato que se preze, ainda estou apanhado para algumas funcionalidades. Toda vez que commito um projeto e o levo para o repositório do GitHub, sempre o projeto anterior vai junto. E eu não sei por que, pois quando uso "git status", apenas os meus arquivos que quero levar para o repositório estão commitados.

[image: Imagem]

O projeto "Clinicall" que é o intruso, é esquisito porque o timer diz que ele está há 1 mês ali. É um erro meu no GitHub ou eu estou commitando o projeto "Clinicall" sem saber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine o seguinte cenário:

Eu tenho um directório que chamo que `Workspace` e dentro deste directório tenho todos os meus projectos. Exemplos:

- Workspace/projecto1
- Workspace/projecto2
- Workspace/projecto3

Caso eu queira mandar o `projecto1` para Github, eu devo inicializar o git dentro deste projecto1 e não dentro do workspace.

Ou seja, se eu rodar o comando `git init .` dentro de `Workspace` todo projecto que estiver dentro de Workspace passará a fazer parte de um único repositório.

Para que eu envie os três projectos de forma separada, ou seja, como repositórios separados, preciso iniciar o git dentro de cada projecto. Ou seja, entro no projecto1 e inicializo o git:

```
$ cd Workspace/projecto1
$ git init .
```

E assim sucessivamente.